# how to have a image refreshing acording to the clock?

Tags: actionscript, flash-cs4

I want to have 3 computers side by side refreshing a fullscreen image at certain times.

how can i do that?

computer 1 - refresh one image every day at 00:00am (365 images/year)
computer 2 - refresh one image every minute (1440 images/day)
computer 3 - refresh one image every second in 60seconds loops (60 images/minute)

And this has to work based in the computer clock if possible so at
00:00am all 3 computers change the image, and every minute computer 2
and 3 change image too.

This can be done with actionscript, right? If so, how?

I was trying with onclipevent (enterframe) and then getting the time and based with the time load a specific image. but i guess i can't use the loadimage on onclipevent, right?

I'm not used to as3 so any help with as2 would be better.

I was trying something like this for the computer 3 scenario:

```
 onClipEvent (enterFrame) {
 time = new Date();
 s = time.getSeconds();

 tv3 = s;
 DSC = "DSC_000";
 jpg = ".jpg";

 var movieClip:MovieClip = createEmptyMovieClip("movieClip", 0);
 movieClip.loadMovie(DSC+tv3+jpg);

 }
```

This will run on a computer so the loading i hope to be as fast as the computer. But this don't work as it's contantly being called and the images don't even load.

Anyone can help?

Comment: I don't know why you are doing, but are you using a COMPUTER just to show an image in fullscreen mode ?!

Comment: I guess you didn't read my post.

Comment: Of course I did, but I want to suggest you to use something like [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) instead of a "normal" computer ...